# HTML Elements not entering top bar

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a simple website to develop my skills in HTML and CSS. I have been having a problem where I can't seem to make some elements in a class enter a bar along the top of the page.

Here is a snippit of the html.

```
<body>
    <!-- A logo will go here but here is some text for now -->
    <h1 ID="Logo">Website</h1>
    <img Class="Social" src="assets/facebook.png"/>
    <img Class="Social" src="assets/twitter.png"/>
    <img Class="Social" src="assets/instagram.png"/>
    <img Class="Social" src="assets/snapchat.png"/>
    <!-- The menu bar -->
    <ul class="menu" ID="Menu_Bar">
        <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Home">
            <a Class="Menu_Link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="About_Us">
            <a Class="Menu_Link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Events">
            <a Class="Menu_Link" href="events.html">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Contact">
            <a Class="Menu_Link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- An image-->
    <img ID="theGang" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg"/>
</body>
```

The ID Logo makes a top bar that stretches accross the entire top of the screen, I can't seem to make the items in class "Social" enter this top bar. They seem to sit directly beneath it.

Here is the css.

```
/* allows elements to use the full lengths of the webpage */
* {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* this is the formatting for the logo */
#Logo{
    font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #2E2F44;
    background-color: #DE1B2B;
}

.Social {
  float: right;

}

/*
*=== Formats the menu bar for the webpage
*===Begin===*
*/
.menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2E2F44;
    font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.Menu_Item{
    float: left;
}

.Menu_Item .Menu_Link {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Menu_Item .Menu_Link:hover {
    background-color: #DE1B2B;
}
/*
*===End===*
*/

/* Formats the header image, 'z-index' makes the image fall behind the nav bar */
#theGang{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add `display: inline-block` to `#Logo` css rules, that will keep `#Logo` on the left, and the `.Social` elements next to it, is that what you are looking for or you want to keep that red bar and the `.Social` elements next to the "Website" word?

Comment: Hi Diego, Thank you for your reply. I have added this change and it has indeed shifted the social elements up. However the red bar is no longer spanning the width of the page

Comment: Ok, that answer my question, let me help on that with a code chunk

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5qwre3vx/ here you will find the code you provided with 2 changes. I added a div wrapping logo and social elements, then added #logo_container on the css and moved the background-color from the logo to this new element. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Diego is right. Wrapping the logo and and social elements allows you to properly apply floats.

You can also consider using Flexbox to apply layout to your page elements without having to rely on floats; it's also considered a more semantic approach lately. Here's another example using flexbox properties:

```css
/* allows elements to use the full lengths of the webpage */

* {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* this is the formatting for the logo */

#Logo {
  font-size: 80px;
}

.logo-section {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;
  color: #2E2F44;
  background-color: #DE1B2B;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.Social {
  width: 24px;
}


/*
*=== Formats the menu bar for the webpage
*===Begin===*
*/

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2E2F44;
  font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Menu_Item {
  float: left;
}

.Menu_Item .Menu_Link {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Menu_Item .Menu_Link:hover {
  background-color: #DE1B2B;
}


/*
*===End===*
*/


/* Formats the header image, 'z-index' makes the image fall behind the nav bar */

#theGang {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- A logo will go here but here is some text for now -->
  <section class="logo-section">
    <h1 ID="Logo">Website</h1>

    <div class="social-icons">
      <img Class="Social" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/svgs/fi-social-facebook.svg" />
      <img Class="Social" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/svgs/fi-social-twitter.svg" />
      <img Class="Social" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/svgs/fi-social-instagram.svg" />
      <img Class="Social" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/svgs/fi-social-snapchat.svg" />
    </div>
  </section>

  <nav>
    <!-- The menu bar -->
    <ul class="menu" ID="Menu_Bar">
      <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Home">
        <a Class="Menu_Link" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="About_Us">
        <a Class="Menu_Link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Events">
        <a Class="Menu_Link" href="events.html">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Contact">
        <a Class="Menu_Link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- An image-->
  <img ID="theGang" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</body>
```